# Explanation of this factorial while function

Tags: javascript

I have tested with console logs, but after several tries I still could not figure it out how this function comes to that output. Number 6 in this case will be put in the parameter of this function named thingamajig and the else statement throws out an execution. But then I got lost at the facky execution. I understand the size execution, only how comes it that facky will outputs 6, 30, 120, 360, 720?

```js
function clunk(times) {
 var num = times; 
 while (num > 0) {
  display("clunk");
  num = num -1;
 }
}

function thingamajig(size) {
 var facky = 1;
 clunkCounter = 0;
 if (size == 0) {
  display("clank");
 } else if (size == 1) {
  display("thunk");
 } else {
  while (size > 1) {
   facky = facky * size; //outputs 6, 30, 120, 360, 720
   size = size - 1; //outputs 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
  }
  clunk(facky);
 }
}

function display(output) {
 console.log(output);
 clunkCounter = clunkCounter + 1;
}

var clunkCounter = 0;
thingamajig(6);
console.log(clunkCounter);
```

Comment: `1 * 6 = 6; 6 * (6 - 1) = 30; 30 * (6 - 2) = 120` etc. You reassign `facky` on every iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how comes it that facky will outputs 6, 30, 120, 360, 720?

This is basically a factorial implementation,

for `size == 6`

```
6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 = 720
```

and so forth.

Comment: Oke stupid me, I was already familiar with factorial. But could not link that to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
When you send to thingamajig size 6
facky will be 6*5*4*3*2

When you send size 30,
facky will be 30*29*28....*2
etc.

So,
If you send 3 - facky will be 6 (3*2)